# Laravel Livewire does not work properly after component is loaded and method is triggered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

can someone guide me through the issue with laravel livewire v2.

I get this message in the console when I load the component and reload the page: https://prnt.sc/SBxT91yu2JTR

Now this is the code from my blade component

```
<div>
    <button type="button" wire:click="triggerCustomMethod">Trigger</button>
</div>
```

And this is the class code

```
    public function triggerCustomMethod()
    {
        dd('I am here');
    }
```

What is going on? :D

Comment: Is this blade component a child of another livewire component? Because it feels this error is not related to the code you posted here.

Comment: Try returning json `return response()->json(['message' => 'I am here']);`